# iTMSTransporter metadata.xml md5 utility ios

Tags: ios, metadata, md5, utility, achievements

So I have 100 achievements to upload, rather than using the website I thought it may be faster to create a metadata.xml file and use iTMSTransporter to upload the data.  Unfortunately one snag is a MD5 checksum must be computed for each image file, or Apple rejects the entire itmsp package.  Requiring this almost invalidates the whole "ease" of using iTMSTransporter.

Is there a utility to parse the metadata file and update it with the checksums?  Or perhaps something which generates a metadata file and does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a command line program that will generate the `metadata.xml` file and compute the files' checksums. It requires you to put your metadata in a YAML file which it turns into a `metadata.xml`: https://github.com/colinhumber/itunes_transporter_generator

You can use this script to update a directory containing a `metadata.xml` file (or files) and assets:

```
require "rexml/document"
require "digest"

def set_checksum(path)
  xml = File.read(path)
  doc = Document.new(xml)
  doc.get_elements("//achievement//file_name").each do |e|  
    next unless e.text =~ /\S/

    file = File.join($source, e.text.strip)
    puts "Computing checksum for #{file}"

    $md5.file(file)
    checksum = $md5.hexdigest!

    node = e.parent.elements["checksum"]
    node = Element.new("checksum", e.parent) unless node
    node.text = checksum 
    node.add_attribute("type", "md5")
  end

  puts "Saving update file"
  File.write(path, doc.to_s)
end

include REXML

$source = ARGV.shift || Dir.pwd
$md5 = Digest::MD5.new
Dir["#$source/*.xml"].each do |path| 
  puts "Processing #{path}"
  set_checksum(path) 
end
```

Use it as follows:

```
> ruby script.rb
```

or

```
> ruby script.rb /path/to/metadata/directory
```

Comment: I wish I had seen that before I wrote my own solution!